# PrimeNG - dataTable header grouping with headerColumnGroup

Tags: user-interface, angular, primeng

I have to group some of the table headers. I made a test using the following code, to see how the **p-headerColumnGroup**  is working.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="sales">
<p-headerColumnGroup>
    <p-row>
        <p-column header="Brand" rowspan="3"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Sale Rate" colspan="4"></p-column>
    </p-row>
    <p-row>
        <p-column header="Sales" colspan="2"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Profits" colspan="2"></p-column>
    </p-row>
    <p-row>
        <p-column header="Last Year"></p-column>
        <p-column header="This Year"></p-column>
        <p-column header="Last Year"></p-column>
        <p-column header="This Year"></p-column>
    </p-row>
</p-headerColumnGroup>

<p-column value="brand"></p-column>
<p-column field="lastYearSale"></p-column>
<p-column field="thisYearSale"></p-column>
<p-column field="lastYearProfit"></p-column>
<p-column field="thisYearProfit"></p-column>

<p-footerColumnGroup>
    <p-row>
        <p-column footer="Totals:" colspan="3"></p-column>
        <p-column footer="$506,202"></p-column>
        <p-column footer="$531,020"></p-column>
    </p-row>
</p-footerColumnGroup>
```

The code should be correct, but the result is not what I'm expecting. I'm using primeng  1.0.0-beta.3

[image: The table looks like:]

Answer (score 1):

[image]PrimeNG now available  1.0.0-rc.3.When i test with 1.0.0-rc.3 version that all things work.Check PrimeNG version here https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng and you need to add  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />` css files in index.html

Comment: I tried to made a primeng update to 1.0.0-rc.2 version, but I have some problems with dependencies. How you dependencies list (pakage.json) looks like?

Comment: i think this problem related with css files please check my answer again.

Comment: I'm no able to update my primeng version to the latest version. My package.json dependencie looks like:

 "dependencies":{
 "angular2":"2.0.0-beta.15",
 "client-http":"0.0.7",
 "systemjs":"0.19.25",
 "es6-shim":"^0.35.0",
 "reflect-metadata":"0.1.2",
 "rxjs":"5.0.0-beta.2",
 "zone.js":"0.6.10",
 "primeng":"1.0.0-beta.3",
 "primeui":"4.1.8"
},
 "devDependencies":{
 "concurrently":"^2.0.0",
 "lite-server":"^2.1.0",
 "typescript":"^1.8.9",
 "typings":"^0.7.9"